# Updating list in-place

Tags: python, list, updates

I have a list of strings, some of them ends with new line symbol. I want to modify this list by removing \n from strings which ends with it. For this purpose I use the following code:

```
aList = ['qwerttyy\n', '123454\n', 'zxcv']

for s in aList:
    if s.endswith('\n'):
    s = s[: -1]
        print(s)
```

The output is the following:

```
    qwerttyy
    123454
    >>> aList
    ['qwerttyy\n', '123454\n', 'zxcv']
```

So the original list wasn't changed though list is mutable object. What is the reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slice assignment and a list comprehension:

```
>>> foo = aList = ['qwerttyy\n', '123454\n', 'zxcv']
>>> aList[:] = [s[:-1] if s.endswith('\n') else s for s in aList]
>>> foo                         #All references are affected.
['qwerttyy', '123454', 'zxcv']
>>> aList
['qwerttyy', '123454', 'zxcv']
```

Your code didn't work because it is equivalent to:

```
s = aList[0]
if s.endswith('\n'):
    s = s[: -1]
s = aList[1]
if s.endswith('\n'):
    s = s[: -1]
...
```

i.e You're updating the variable `s`, not the actual list item

Answer (score 1):

because the for loop makes copies of strings.

You can use:
`[s[:-1] if s.endswith('\n') else s for s in aList]`

Maybe this is simpler, though it will remove also whitespaces.
`[s.strip() for s in aList]`

Comment: This doesn't modify the list _on place_.

Comment: Ok. Then re-affect the lsit: aList = [s[:-1] if s.endswith('\n') else s for s in aList]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
>>> aList = ['qwerttyy\n', '123454\n', 'zxcv']
>>> aList = [x[:-1] if x.endswith('\n') else x for x in aList]
>>> aList
['qwerttyy', '123454', 'zxcv']
```

Comment: Not quite right, you dropped a 'v' in the 3rd element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.rstrip)

```
>>> aList = ['qwerttyy\n', '123454\n', 'zxcv']
>>> [s.rstrip('\n') for s in aList]
['qwerttyy', '123454', 'zxcv']
```

Above will create new list. To modify the original list, use slicing (`list[:] = ...`):

```
>>> aList
['qwerttyy\n', '123454\n', 'zxcv']
>>> aList[:] = [s.rstrip('\n') for s in aList]
>>> aList
['qwerttyy', '123454', 'zxcv']
```

**NOTE** `str.rstrip` returns different result from `[:-1]` when tehre are multiple trailing newlines:

```
>>> 'qwerttyy\n\n'.rstrip('\n')
'qwerttyy'
>>> 'qwerttyy\n\n'[:-1]
'qwerttyy\n'
```

Comment: Note that there's a difference between `x[:-1]` and `x.strip('\n')` when `x` is something like `'foo\n\n'`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, Thank you for comment. I added a note about it.